# How to find the permutations of a string?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, subset

How can i find the combinations of a particular string....

ABCD - "",A,B,C,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,ABC,ACD,ABD,ABCD,...

C programming language....

tHANKS..

Comment: That's not permutations, that's all possible subsets...

Comment: Try searching this site.

Comment: When I am asking a question I am considering it as if I am programming. I want it to be clear, without spelling mistakes, properly formatted. It makes me cry when I see such questions:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert alphabet that you need in set and call findSubset .

```
Set findSubsets(Set A)
{
     if A is the empty set
            return the empty set

     // The first element of our set is A[0]
     // (A - A[0] is the set A without the first element)
     Set B := findSubsets(A - A[0])

     // Set B is now all the subsets of A without the first element
     // We now find all the subsets of A containing the first element by finding
     // tacking on the first element to the sets inside B
     Set C = {}
     For each set D in B
            add {A[0], D} to C

    return B added to C
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the standard library [ìtertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) should help. Take a look at `combinations()` function, maybe others depending what *exacly* you want. Do you want to have repeats allowed? Is the order important?

Comment: Need to program.. understand the logic...

Comment: first, you need to phrase your question more precise. The terms *permutations* and *combinations* are defined as different terms, and then, your description points to *subsets*...